# Do I need to import SSL chain in order?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, truststore

I have an SSL certificate which is signed by intermediate CA and then Intermediate CA certificate is signed by the root CA. 
I need to import these certificates to my truststore in order to access this service.

My questions is - Is there any particular order that I need to follow for importing these certs.

for example import SSL cert first, then intermediate CA cert and then root CA cert

OR I can import certificate in any order and be confident that it will work.

2nd part of the question - WHEN PKIX path building happens does it care about the order in which certs are present in the truststore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the order of the certificates in the truststore is irrelevant.

When the certification chain presented by the server is validated, the client searches for a match in the truststore, starting with the final certificate up to the root. Each certificate is validated using the public key of the upper certificate until a match with the truststore is found. There is a match when the certificate itself is present or its immediate superior (The certificate has been digitally signed by the upper certificate).

Therefore the order does not matter because the digital signature of each certificate in the chain is going to be validated

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As a 2023 add to this.  We were loading up the latest version of Coldfusion 2023.  And, we as a previous version of Coldfusion 2018.   What we found out was the Jre cacerts INDEED had to be in the correct order.  I followed the order/path as suggested in the reply above.  BUT, you need to have imported them in the order starting with the final cert and this back up.   Just a very "learned" by fighting with the issue twice now.  Might be different in you java setup.  But, in ours, we add to have the correct order or it would not work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).